# Azure Mobile app don't list web services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

This is driving me crazy. Testing Azure backend app to see my services, the TRY OUT Link doest not show in the page. Therefore I can't access the services list. However the mobile app pages shows perfectly saying that "This mobile app is up and running"

Tried entering the URL directly localhost:51550/Help and the server returns 404

Comment: Stackoverflow is about code. This is not a code issue. You might find answers on the Superuser site. http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

See [Azure App Service Mobile - Try It Out not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552068/azure-app-service-mobile-try-it-out-not-visible). The Try it Out button has been removed in Azure Mobile Apps, in favor of Swagger support. See [Adding Swagger Metadata and Help UI to a Mobile App](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Adding-Swagger-Metadata-and-Help-UI-to-a-Mobile-App).