# Azure App Service Mobile - Try It Out not visible

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I started a prototype project using App Service Mobile Apps few months ago and then left it alone.

Today I grabbed the code and tried to run it again. It compiled and seems to be running fine. But I'm unable to test access to the APIs. Previously there used to be ***Try It Out*** link there, where I can access the apis. But now I can't find it anymore. Accessing the url **/help**  but its showing 404 error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Try it Out button has been removed in Azure Mobile Apps, in favor of Swagger support. See [Adding Swagger Metadata and Help UI to a Mobile App](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Adding-Swagger-Metadata-and-Help-UI-to-a-Mobile-App).